# DateTime source string format in jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have jQuery DataTable that I populate it from SQL DataBase. I recive datetime in this format : `2020-08-26T23:45:51.35` and I want to format the string that I recive from DataBase.

This is what I tryed:

```
....
 columnDefs:
            [
                {
                    render: function (data) {
                        return (moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY, <br> HH:mm:ss:SSS')); 
                        console.log(data),
                    },
                    targets: 3,
                    className: "text-nowrap"
                },
           ]
```

But this insert the current date, not the date that I receive from DataBase.

Any suggestions how to format the string date that I received from DataBase?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
 columnDefs:
        [
            {
                render: function (data) {
                    return (moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')); 
                    console.log(data),
                },
                targets: 3,
                className: "text-nowrap"
            },
       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the datetime from the database to moment to format it, so it is getting just the local time.

```
return (moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS'));
```

For format I always use dd/mm/YYYY HH:mm:ss

Comment: OK. I want only numbers thats why I put `DD/MM/YYYY`